# I would like to insulate for winter and allow cooling in the summer for some equipment that is in a building with no heat or AC

Tags: router, wireless, environmental-monitoring

I have 2 sheds basically, one shed has a router (used as bridge) and a time clock.

The time clock will be fine in the summer but in the winter I think I need some kind of insulation to protect it. (maybe sticky on 1 side?) they are not cheap devices. 
The router used as a bridge needs both insulation and a fan for cooling I'm guessing. I plan on building a box with vents and wiring in a little fan but I'm not sure of which insulation to use? or heat supply to use. (at night when the temps drop the device will not be in use and will have no heat source of it's own.

The other shed has a camera systems dvr. Ill put a little fan in and some vents                                               also there are lots of wires and self-made heat, but I should probably line the box in some kind of insulation for the really cold nights?

Any thoughts or idea's would be greatly appreciated.

In a perfect situation I would purchase the best outdoor wifi-extender or router and remove the DVR and place all 20 camera's on the cloud. Unfortunately my client does not want to spend the money for good equipment nor does he want to run heat in the 2 buildings all winter long.

Thank you

"crazy-mess of things"

where clients end up with NO previous IT support

Comment: What temperature ranges are we talking about (high/low)?

Comment: In the Summer I expect it to get up into the 100's but not consistently. It will stay between 85º - 90º F for a few weeks straight. and in the Winter it will stay between 0º and 20º F but also could drop down to no more than -20º F some nights. Thank You for your time

Comment: If the temperature gets above the maximum listed operating temperature for the equipment (likely 95), the equipment probably won't last very long, even with fans blowing on it. This could be a case where the client spends more money replacing equipment than if he had bought the right equipment in the first place. I know someone who replaced a router one to three times a year because she was too cheap to buy an industrial router designed for the conditions.

Comment: Yes, I agree 1000%. He seems to think it will be fine (lol). Sometimes he has slow connections, which couldn't be the 10-15 cell phones connecting and disconnecting all day long not to mention the 12 camera's, 2 time clocks, and then 2 laptops connected to it daily. but who's counting right. 
If he's dead set on keeping the current situation. I'll build the boxes and when it just isn't enough and they start failing, I think he will see the light and just say fix it the right way. He's not totally ignorant and will see the value in it. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems *very* tenuous as far as being on topic. However.

Simply build or buy a very well insulated box (rack case), and provide vents that can be opened, or closed, depending on temperatures inside and out - assist with fans as required. If the router is on all night and makes heat, sufficient insulation will be all that's required. Otherwise a basic ceramic heater and a thermostat. Be sure to check the devices specified operating temperature range, so that you are not heating the enclosure beyond what the device actually requires - many things are quite happy to be quite cold, so long as moisture is kept out of them.

What type of insulation really does not matter - whatever is easy. Foam sheets, loose cellulose and a frame/box to contain it, etc. If you have a wifi antenna inside the box, don't use foil-faced insulation.

Alternatively, take the thoroughly professional approach of dropping the cheapskate client.

**Edit, add:** On the hot side, it will cost much less to run an air conditioner that cools the well-insulated box than to run one to cool a whole building, if it gets too hot for just fans to be effective.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, Allowing vents to be open & closed is a very good idea I did not consider. Yes I have checked the operating temp and it is:
32° ~ 104° F / 0° ~ 40° C
Humidity 10 ~ 90% NC
I suppose the device will be good in the summer with appropriate venting, but the winter I will need a temp monitor to check how cold it does get in the box I build, and I'll make some adjustments if it gets close to the danger zone.
Again Great Idea with the close-able vents, and thank you very much for your time. @Ecnerwal